# CPU/RAM usage isn't updating when using a DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to make a CPU/RAM usage number show up in my program. I'm using a DispatcherTimer set to an interval of 1 second, but each time it gets the same number for the usage (RAM: 82% CPU: 0%). I also have a DateTime.Now set up and it seems to update every second, so im not sure what exactly is happening. The Window_Loaded method is set to "Loaded" in XAML.

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //creates a new dispatchertimer called timer
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            //sets the timer interval to update every 1 second
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            //calls the method that updates the time, shows the RAM usage and CPU usage
            timer.Tick += DisplayInformation;
            //starts the timer
            timer.Start();
        }
```

```
        private void DisplayInformation(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //creates two varibles to hold the % usage of RAM and CPU
            var cpuUsage = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
            var ramUsage = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "% Committed Bytes In Use", null);

            //sets the clock label to the current time of day
            TimeOfDay.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

            //sets the CPU and RAM labels to the the usage variables
            CPUdisplay.Content = $"    CPU Usage:   {(int)cpuUsage.NextValue()}%";
            RAMdisplay.Content = $"    RAM Usage:   {(int)ramUsage.NextValue()}%";
        }
```

Comment: You must not create new PerformanceCounters on each timer tick. Create them once, then query the existing ones.

Comment: @Clemens That was exactly the problem. Thank you for the help!